# How to get rails work together with AngularJS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4

Now I have used couple of hours to integrate rails work together with angular, and I am about to give up. I am following this tutorial:

[link to tutorial](http://asanderson.org/posts/2013/06/03/bootstrapping-angular-rails-part-1.html)

'
and I made it even simpler

In my application.js I require the following :

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require angular
```

in my main.js.coffe I ask to get the following js files :

```
#= require_self
#= require_tree ./controllers/main
```

and in my `app/assets/javascripts/controllers/main/mainIndexCtrl.js.cofee` I have the same lines as he does in tutorial :

```
@IndexCtrl = ($scope) ->
  $scope.title = "My blog"
```

So here is the funny part :

my "Master" view is exactly the same as in tutorial :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
  <title>Blog</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", controller_name %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

So in theory when I run my app at `http://localhost:3000/main/Index` I should get the exact same result as he does, but no.

I am getting Runtime error, which says that it has failed at  `(in /app/assets/javascripts/main.js.coffee)` and nothing else. I really can't figure out what exactly is going wrong. If I switch controller_name with some random string like 'hugabuga' page loads and of course angular wont work because there are no link to the controller Index.

I am not very experienced with cofee script, but maybe the way controller is defined is not correct?

Comment: Did you added _angular gem_ in your `gemfile` and run `bundle install`?

Comment: yes i did, just double checked it

Comment: you mean angularjs-rails right?

Comment: Whichever are using in the tutorial. They manualy downloaded angular and underscore. Did you do the same?

Comment: Yes i did, and added it exactly same place

Comment: I just reference angular on a cdn

Comment: I am facing the exact same problem.

Answer (score 0):

In another tutorial I had to add another Gem

```
gem 'angular-rails-templates'
```

And also amend the application.js to include:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require angular/angular
//= require angular-route/angular-route
//= require angular-rails-templates
//= require_tree .
```

The order that the JS is listed is also important. Make sure you have the same in your file as what is shown in the video.